# $ab=0 \Rightarrow b$ is nilpotent in a Noetherian ring

Tags: noetherian, nilpotence, division-ring

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $a \in A$. Show that if $a$ is not contained in a minimal prime, $ab=0 \Rightarrow b$ is nilpotent.

I can't see a way to solve this. I tried to consider that in a Noetherian ring the nilradical is nilpotent, but I don't know how to use it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The nilradical is the intersection of all minimal primes (whether $A$ is noetherian or not).

Comment: so, $a$ does not belong to the nilradical. But how I conclude that $b$ does?

Comment: If $a$ is not in any minimal prime, $b$ is.

Comment: why? and assuming that $b$ belongs to a minimal prime, how ca I show that it belongs to the nilradical? $b$ can be in a minimal prime without being in the nilradical, right? thanks for your help in understanding minimal primes

Comment: If $a$ is in *no* minimal prime, $b$ is in *all* minimal primes, hence in their intersection.